# Fan control thinks my SSD has about 100 degree celsius

Tags: ssd, temperature, fancontrol

my fan is driving me crazy. It is continously running. I think I know why this is happening. If I run psensor, my SSD HD (from udisks2) is listed to be 100 degree hot. But if I use hddtemp, it tells me that the temperature is about 30 degree. My question is, how can I override the udisks2 sensor temperature or switch it off?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with an i7 and NVIDIA Graphic Optimus Card.

Thank you very much in advance.
    Franz

Comment: Your problem most likely comes from running a development release. Report it as a bug on Launchpad.